# jQuery: appending loaded url with class of trigger

Tags: jquery, ajax, class

I'm using jQuery to load a section through ajax. I'd like to make a very universal, compact function to load up the appropriate section based on a clicked tab.

Here's the tricky part.

I'd like to take the class of the tab that is clicked and append the url that will be loaded with the class the tab has.
This is what I have so far, and I'm sure it can be make more compact.

JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "<img src='../../images/icons/loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

var loadUrl = "/include/?section=accountsettings&view=";

$("#accountsettings").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl + "accountsettings");

$(".filterCat a").click(function(){
    $("#contentSm div").fadeOut(200);
});

$(".accountsettings").click(function(){
    $("#accountsettings").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl + "accountsettings");
    $("#accountsettings").delay(250).fadeIn(250);
});

$(".editprofile").click(function(){
    $("#editprofile").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl + "editprofile");
    $("#editprofile").delay(250).fadeIn(250);
});

$(".notifications").click(function(){
    $("#notifications").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl + "notifications");
    $("#notifications").delay(250).fadeIn(250);
});

$(".broadcast").click(function(){
    $("#broadcast").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl + "broadcast");
    $("#broadcast").delay(250).fadeIn(250);
});

$(".import").click(function(){
    $("#import").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl + "import");
    $("#import").delay(250).fadeIn(250);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="filter" class="span-3">
    <div id="accountSettingsTabs">
        <div class="filterCat section">
            <a class="accountsettings sel"><span class="wIcon accountSet"></span>Account</a>
            <a class="editprofile"><span class="wIcon send"></span>Edit Profile</a>
            <a class="notifications"><span class="wIcon emailNoti"></span>Notifications</a>
            <a class="broadcast"><span class="wIcon broadcast"></span>Broadcast</a>
            <a class="import"><span class="wIcon import"></span>Import</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentSm" class="span-8">
    <div id="accountsettings" class="section"></div>
    <div id="editprofile" class="section"></div>
    <div id="notifications" class="section"></div>
    <div id="broadcast" class="section"></div>
    <div id="import" class="section"></div>
</div>
```

So I'm looking to append /include/?section=accountsettings&view= with the first class of the clicked anchor.
I'll try whatever you can think up! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create tab like this

```
<a class="ajaxifiedTab notifications" _param="notifications" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var loadUrl = "/include/?section=accountsettings&view=";
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('.ajaxifiedTab').bind('click',function(e){    
       e.preventDefault();
       var _class=jQuery(e.target).attr('_param');
       jQuery.ajax({
            url:loadUrl +_class,
            type:'get',  //or post as u think
            success:function(data){
                jQuery('#'+_class).html(data);
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: **Thanks so much**. This will give me a really solid place to build from. This works really well, but fyi for anyone else looking at this, I believe you need a comma after `type:'get'`.